# SharePoint Online Search Display Template

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, display-template

I am working on customizing the Search Results page by modifying the item display template. I have managed to add managed properties and display it in search results. The requirement is that I need to modify the title link (href) to a different hyperlink value (list column) rather than the default path. I am not sure how to achieve this.

Also right now description is not being shown for the result items if the description does not have the searched keyword. I need to show the description of the list item even if the description field does not contain the keyword.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.